# Resistor operating temperature range

Tags: resistors, temperature

Possible market have the resistor spec as below?
RES. 68R 1/8W 1% SMD0805 -55'C/+175'C

Comment: Why don't you check it out from Digikey or Mouser? Search for "chip resistor" then select resistance, temperature level and case.

Comment: Its your task to get the heat out, and prevent a fire. At 10X the power rating, you get smoke. At 50X, you get instant fire.

Comment: I ady checked. for the resistance, case, voltage, tolerance can meet my requirement. But for the operating temperature range only get -55C/+155C. So i am so confuse for this.

Comment: So this spec is reasonable?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @mkeith At first I couldn't as well but after 3-4 reads, I could :) OP asks for a 68R 0805 case chip resistor with a tolerance of %1 and an operating temperature range of -55..+175°C.

Comment: Does it need to be an 0805? I would reevaluate whether it is worth the effort to find something that specific as there are several resistors available for that value, precision, and temperature rating if you are willing to go to a larger package. For example, https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/riedon/S2-68RF1/696-1211-2-ND/1834154

Comment: I wonder, if the operating temperature is 175C, what kind of circuit board is this on? I believe that is too high form most FR4 materials.

Comment: @LosFrijoles yes. It need be 0805.

Comment: @mkeith this is for burn in board.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum continuous working temperature of standard components with nickel/tin terminals is usually specified as +155 °C (tin has a peak temperature of 230 °C while nickel is limited to 160 °C).

By using superior materials, and combining an inner terminal of silver/palladium with a wrap-around of platinum/silver, this is possible.

Riedon is able to offer chip resistors that can work in applications up to 300 °C.

For this >250'C attachment you can use silver epoxy attachment on metal-clad PCB to avoid solder and since there is no nickel, this resistor part is non-magnetic for MRI applications.

### added

Not only Working temp of Resistors but PCB material must meet 175'C

Some suppliers, a customer can also ask for high TG (170-180C) for MCPCB, but the thermal conductivity can only be (0.3-0.4W/m.k).

If printed circuit board working temperature is higher than 170/180C, such as 200C, 280C, or even higher, then you'd better use Ceramic board which can go through -55~880C.

Answer (score 0):

I look up this resistor in digikey. I don't think you will get a standard resistor with this specification. Can you change the package size? In this case i found a  **62Ohm** resistor which should match. But unfortunately it is huge.
Here the link:[62 Ohm resistor from Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/resistors/chip-resistor-surface-mount/52?k=Automotive%20Resistors&k=&pkeyword=Automotive%20Resistors&pv1=1053&FV=ffe00034%2C3f0007c%2C3f000ad%2C3f000d9%2C3f0033c&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)
If you don't linke this solution you should try to change your specification. E.g. you could use a heat sink.
Otherwise you could describe your development plan. Perhaps there are other more efficient solutions.

Comment: those are wirewound